# Having trouble getting multiple dialogs to position in relation to one another

Tags: jquery, dialog, position

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.   I'm wanting to line up two dialogs on top of one another. "Top" on top and "bottom" on the bottom.   The positioning doesn't seem to be working.

### Here's my html

```
<body> 
<div id="top">
  <p>This is the top element.</p>
</div>

<div id="bottom">
  <p>bottom element</p>
</div>
</body>
```

### Here's my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#top').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 300
    });  

    $('#bottom').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 200,
        position: {
                of: $('#top'),
                my: 'top left',
                at: 'bottom left'
            }
    });  
  });
```

### And my CSS

```
#top {
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    background-color: #fbca93;
    text-align: center;
}

#bottom {
    border: 1px solid #777;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I was able to get it working by adding the following line after the dialog creation.   I'm still confused why the position parameter in the dialog init doesn't do the same thing.      $('#bottom').dialog({ position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: $('#top') } });